# goaccess nginx logformat issue

Tags: nginx, goaccess

Just installed `goaccess`, and i want to parse nginx log, but can't understand how to make right log-format. In nginx.conf i have this format

```
'$server_addr $server_port $remote_addr $request_time $upstream_response_time $time_iso8601 $request  $status $body_bytes_sent';
```

And a peace of log from file

```
192.168.2.35 8382 192.168.2.98 38.547 38.547 2016-01-14T13:30:22+02:00 POST /test/search?id=4587252-16 HTTP/1.1 200 4185
```

In the goaccess conf file, i have this format

```
date_format %Y/%m/%d  
time-format %H:%M:%S  
log-format %h %^ %r %T %^ %^ %r %s %b
```

but get an error

> "Nothing valid to process. Verify your date/time/log format"

Answer (score 1):

You may try this format:

```
log-format %^ %^ %h %T %^ %dT%t+%^ %m %U %H %s %b
date-format %Y-%m-%d
time-format %H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Thanks. I have made it before your wrote this.. but in your template i see in "Bandwidth" only 0 bytes...  Whatever, thanks for help